# JPA Entity by extending a MappedSuperclass POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Keyword {
        private Integer code;
        private Integer rating;

        public Keyword() {}

        public Integer getCode() {
            return this.code;
        }

        public Integer getRating() {
            return this.rating;
        }

        public void setCode(Integer code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public void setRating(Integer rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }
}
```

I <s>want</s> to create an `Entity` by extending this class and I want to set an already existing field as the primary key (I don't want to create new fields), so I tried to do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "keyword")
//@AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "code"))
public class MyKeyword extends Keyword {
    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getCode() {
        return super.getCode();
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error when ran

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: com.foo.model.MyKeyword column: code (should be mapped
>   with insert="false" update="false")

Any idea how can I properly configure this up? Keep in mind I have no access to the MappedSuperclass, I can't modify it whatsoever.

Comment: Why are you using @AttributeOverride? As the field code has no mapping declared in the super class.

Comment: @simas_ch True, it's unnecessary, I commented it in the code above not to confuse any readers, thanks for the tip. Any idea about the main issue?

Comment: Also if I understand correctly the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation on the super class is unnecessary too as there are no mappings defined there.

Comment: Just did a quick proof of concept by removing `@MappedSuperClass` from the super class and simply overriding/annotating the methods in my child class and it worked. No idea how to make it work while having `@MappedSuperClass` in the super class.

Comment: The @MappSuperClass is not unnecessary because if it is not present then private Integer rating; will not be mapped.